# tengo un problema con mi hitbox

Tags: javascript, html, game

bien pues estoy haciendo un proyecto con javascript de un juego mientras voy aprendiendo mas cosas sobre el.

intente hacer un hitbox pero no me sale.Lo formule con el if si se pasaba del x o el y del canvas , se restaba a su posicion haciendo el efecto de que no se mueve.

obviamente no lo hiso y quiero saber que ideas tienen acerca de como hacer uno.

intenta ir a la derecha veraz que no funciona.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <input id="text" type="text" value="COLEGA"><br>
        <canvas id="camara" width="500" height="500" style="border:5px solid #000000">
        
        <script>
            
            //creando el objecto personaje:
            var Personaje = {
                cx: 250,
                cy: 250,
                control: function(){
                    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {                   
                        if(e.key=="w"){
                            Personaje.cy = Personaje.cy - 1
                        }else if(e.key=="a"){
                            Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx - 1
                        }else if(e.key=="s"){
                            Personaje.cy = Personaje.cy + 1
                        }else if(e.key=="d"){
                            Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx + 1
                        }else if(Personaje.cx == 500)
                            Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx -2
                        }else{
                            console.log("nada importante");
                        }
                    })
                },
            };
            //variables globales:
            var canvas;
            var ctx;
            var velocidad = 7;
            
            //creando bucles:
            //bucle de tiempo
            for(velocidad;velocidad<10;velocidad++){
                Personaje.control();
            };
            //bucle general
            setInterval(function(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
                ctx.drawImage(img,Personaje.cx,Personaje.cy);
                var info = document.getElementById("text").value;
                ctx.fillText(info,Personaje.cx,Personaje.cy);
            },10);
            //iniciando canvas
            canvas = document.getElementById("camara");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            //dibujando personaje   
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "pixie.png";
            ctx.drawImage(img,Personaje.cx,Personaje.cy);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberias colocar el codigo con comentarios y todo, para que sea más facil ayudarte

Comment: ok tiene comentarios y todo lo editare y veremos si puedes ayudarme

Comment: Por favor coloca un [ejemplo minimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ayudarte

Comment: ya lo hice ya puedes verificarlo

Comment: ejemplo mínimo *verificable* no significa que debamos *verificarlo* nosotros. Significa que cuando tienes problemas con la depuración, y dado que nuestro cerebro todavía no puede interpretar código, debes proporcionar un ejemplo que podamos pulsar un botón y ver ***qué pasa***.

Comment: ahhh muchas gracias es que soy nuevo

Comment: has intentado usar async await?,veo muchas condicionales apiladas, intenta usar async await para que tu código que vea mejor y se pueda entender y así ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema está en el orden de la lógica de tus condicionales. Fíjate que el que comprueba si se ha salido del área está al final, después de comprobar si se presiona "d".

De tu código:

```javascript
else if(e.key=="d"){
    Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx + 1
}else if(Personaje.cx == 500)
    Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx -2
}
```

La comprobación de `Personaje.cx == 500` te interesa hacerla antes, porque si no va a entrar en `e.key == "d"` y se va a mover a la derecha. Prueba con ese fragmento así:

```javascript
// Si presiona "d" ve a la derecha.
else if(e.key=="d") {
    // Si ya esta en el borde, no va mas a la derecha.
    if(Personaje.cx == 500)
        Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx -2
    }
    else {
        Personaje.cx = Personaje.cx + 1
    }
}
```

Que una vez lo entiendas y lo tengas bien puedes acortarlo así:

```javascript
// Si presiona "d" ve a la derecha.
else if(e.key=="d") {
    // Si no esta en el borde suma 1, si se paso el borde resta 2.
    Personaje.cx += Personaje.cx < 500 ? 1 : -2;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias enserio no lo pense de esa manera y tiene mucho sentido una vez mas gracias